# Gradient is repeating

Tags: html, css

Gradient of the page is repeating itself. I tried to use `background: no repeat` but it is not working properly. I also tried to extend the height of the body to 100% but still it is not working. When I tried to use the same code for another page and used `linear-gradient(to right, red, green)` and `linear-gradient(to left, red, green)`, it worked , but it had the same issue of repeating the gradient when I used `linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green)`. The CSS code is as follows :

```
body{
    height: 100%;
    background: no-repeat;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green);
}
```

Wanted to know why  did this happened ?

Comment: see this link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: you  can use `background-repeat: no-repeat`

Comment: you only need `html {
  min-height: 100%;
}` and you can remove height:100% from the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Height` on `HTML` tag `100%`

```
html{height:100%;}
body{
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, green);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/soujrxyf/3/

Comment: It helped. But, I still not sure why making the body height 100% was not effective ???

Comment: parent tag not full height

Comment: add body `height:100vh` then work